# Reclassify values of raster but max value of output raster seems incorrect

Tags: r

I have already searched for some other questions and found a couple that refer to the `reclassify` function but none of them specifically answer the problem that i seem to have. I have coded the values of a raster containing slope information in degrees incline. Data is extracted within each of my 15 polygons, constructed by GPS points. I would like the categories to be represented by the intervals: `(0, 5, 1, 10, 15, 2, 20, 50, 3)`.

This leaves 3 classes but whenever I run the script below the min / max values of the raster are displayed as the normal spread of the data NOT 0-3 for the newly coded classes.

```
All50HRs <- shapefile("L:\GPSdatabackup\KERNELS\NewHRs50")
plot(All50HRs)
All50HRs
library(raster)
update.packages("raster")
recl <- matrix(c(0, 5, 1, 10, 15, 2, 20, Inf, 3), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rcl <- matrix(ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc <- reclassify(Slope, c(0, 5, 1, 10, 15, 2, 20, 50, 3))
```

Whenever I now call the `image(recl)` command to see the properties of the output raster it has `min = 0` and `max = 19.9` where it should be 3!

Does anyone know why this is as I am relatively new with R?

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to reclassify the values between 5 and 10, and between 15 and 20, so those values remain as they were to begin with.

To correct the problem, fix your reclassification vector/matrix as in the following example:

```
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100, 0, 50), ncol=10))
plot(r)
```

[image]

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 5, 1,
            5, 10, 2,
            10, 15, 3,
            15, 20, 4,
            20, Inf, 5), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
r2 <- reclassify(r, m)
r2

# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 1, 5  (min, max)

plot(r2)
```

[image]

See `?reclassify` for more details.

Comment: I have now adjusted the script reclassification so to include decimals as follows rc <- reclassify(Slope, c(0,10,1,10.1,20,2,20.1,Inf,3))
However, I still am not finding the max' is 3 as i wanted it to be. It seems to be 20 still. Can anyone help as to why this is?

Comment: You should be using `c(0, 10, 1, 10, 20, 2, 20, Inf, 3))`. By default, the lower end is not included in the bracket.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying and suggesting a solution but when i remove the bracket to the left of the "c" i now get this error Error: unexpected symbol in "recl<-matrix c"

Comment: THE TOTAL SCRIPT LOOKS LIKE THIS IF YOU SUSPECT IT MAY BE SOMETHING EARLIER THAT IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM?? THANK YOU SO MUCH AGAIN YOU DON'T KNOW HOW LONG I HAVE BEEN STRUGGLING WITH THIS LITTLE PROBLEM
All50HRs<-shapefile("L:\\GPSdatabackup\\KERNELS\\NewHRs50")
plot(All50HRs)
All50HRs
library(raster)
update.packages("raster")
recl<-matrix c(0,10,1,10.1,20,2,20.1,Inf,3),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
rc <- matrix(ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc <- reclassify(Slope, c(0,10,1,10.1,20,2,20.1,Inf,3))
image(recl)
recl

Comment: @user1667816: I did not mean "remove the bracket". I meant that the lowest value in a range (e.g. the `0` in `c(0, 10, 1)`) is not included in the reclassification. i.e. for `c(0, 10, 1), only values of `x` where `0 < x <= 10` will be reclassified to 1. Did you try my code???

Comment: @user1667816: Please don't type comments in allcaps. If you want to include code in a comment, surround the code with backticks (these: `) so that the code is formatted properly.

Comment: I think i have been working under the assumption that the reclassification command could only have 3 columns but i believe it can have more now so i will change my script slightly.

Comment: @user1667816 It should only have 3 columns if you provide a matrix. If you provide a vector, it will be coerced to a matrix with 3 columns, with `byrow=T`.

Comment: Ok, Sorry about the capitals, and your help has certainly helped for the moment. For the moment i have no further questions :)